# SendGrid Bounce API Curl - Gives "authorization required"

Tags: php, curl, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

So i'm trying to track if an email returns a bounce (address not found)

Here's my code:

```
#Find bounce report.
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, 
array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLAUTH_ANY,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/suppression/bounces/'.$bouncemail.'/',
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 'Authorization: Bearer <<REDACTED>>'
));

$bounce_report = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

I can't seem to find what i'm doing wrong here.

This is what i get:

> authorization required

Maybe some of you can see it?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

You probably want

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER
```

instead of

```
CURLOPT_HEADER
```

as CURLOPT_HEADER is for allowing HEADERS to be returned or not while CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER is what is sent with the request.

Comment: Hey! Sorry for the late answer, just returned from weekend.. I was thinking about that, but that ain't working either.. It still says the same. Thanks for the comment tho! :D

Comment: Okey, I have some more thoughts about not using request methods (you probably want todo a post request). But I think looking into the answers to this question will help more 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426047/correct-way-to-set-bearer-token-with-curl

Answer (score 0):

Your API Key has restricted access.
To give it elevated privileges

#### Go To  :

SendGrid Dashboard > Settings > API Keys > Edit Api Key > Give Full Access to Key > Update

[image: Api Management Console]