# Fetch data through rest API in PHP

Tags: php, rest, curl

I am trying to get the sales order through rest API in PHP from unicommerce.com. The issue is I could not able to understand the parameter to fetch the data from the server via API.
as I understand I successfully get the data from the server [access-token](https://documentation.unicommerce.com/docs/oauth.html) from this page using my credentials,
but I am trying to get [sales-order](https://documentation.unicommerce.com/docs/saleorder-get.html) due to very few parameters I could not understand what I pass to get the data.
The page only showing this data to pass -

*Basic Information*

| NAME | DETAILS |
| --- | --- |
| Endpoint: | /services/rest/v1/oms/saleorder/get |
| Request Type: | POST |
| Level: | Tenant |
| Scheme: | HTTPS |
| Header (Content-Type): | application/json |
| Header (Authorization): | bearer {access-token}, Eg.: bearer b30f3aea-7978-49bb-9ea7-33eddfc80afa |

I am using like this but it not working
and showing the error -

> {"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext"}

```
https://subdomain.unicommerce.com/services/rest/v1/oms/saleorder/get?bearer=b30f3aea-7978-49bb-9ea7-33eddfc80afa
```

Comment: The basic info table you include shows that `bearer` is meant to be passed as a Header, not as part of the query string.  I skimmed through the docs you linked but it doesn't look like they give any examples, but there are plenty here on SO, eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426047/correct-way-to-set-bearer-token-with-curl

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way to set Bearer token with CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426047/correct-way-to-set-bearer-token-with-curl)

Answer (score 1):

use curl with authorization header

```
$requestPayload = [
    'code' => 'string',
    'facilityCodes' => ['string']
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://subdomain.unicommerce.com/services/rest/v1/oms/saleorder/get");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($requestPayload));  //Post Fields
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = [
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer b30f3aea-7978-49bb-9ea7-33eddfc80afa',
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$response = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

var_dump($response);
```

Comment: thank you but it is work on sales order wise. is this not possible to fetch all sales order? also when I use `print_r($response)` it is not show pretty

Comment: read `Request Payload Details` in API document please, `code` for single order or `facilityCodes` for list order

Comment: sir it giving `1619944810000` UTC formate date, can you please chnage in this IST formate