# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "CURLAUTH_BEARER"

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I have this error "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "CURLAUTH_BEARER" when am using "sinch" API to send sms.

I tried other domains on godady and localhost and I have no problem but when I uploading it on my another domain on "http://domeny.pl/" it shows that error.

All PHP version is 8.

```
$content = [
  'to' => array_values($recipient_phone_numbers),
  'from' => $send_from,
  'body' => $message
];

$data = json_encode($content);
$ch = curl_init("https://us.sms.api.sinch.com/xms/v1/{$service_plan_id}/batches");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BEARER);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_XOAUTH2_BEARER, $bearer_token);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
  echo curl_error($ch);
} else {
  echo "Sent .. ! ";
}
```

Comment: Perhaps [this might be of interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426047/correct-way-to-set-bearer-token-with-curl)

Comment: not working :'(

Comment: What version of PHP do you have? I can find no mention of `CURLAUTH_BEARER` as a legitimate PHP constant

Comment: i have version 8

Comment: Check examples from [curl.se](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_XOAUTH2_BEARER.html)

Comment: What version of cURL? From [Predefined Constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.constants.php): "_CURLAUTH_BEARER (int) Available since PHP 7.3.0 and cURL 7.61.0._"